# Why doesn't the outer scope variable get properly bound to the inner variable?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
(function(){
  var x = 23;
  return function(){
    var x = x;
    return x;
  }
}())();
```

Why does it return undefined instead of 23?

Shouldn't the var x = x; part be sufficiently unambiguous because the right hand side implicitly refers to the x in the outer scope?

Comment: I think this can be related with the hoisting of variables: the variable is declared and then assigned, so the right side `x` is the same one that the left side one

Comment: No, because you're returning a function which isn't executed until after the scope of the initial declaration of `x` has gone. It's therefore undefined when you execute it. You should pass `x` into your `return function`

Comment: You don't need `var x = x;`.

Comment: @RGraham I think that is not the reason, because `(function(){ var y = 23;  return function(){ var x = y; return x; }}())();` works

Comment: @Pablo, RobG Thanks, get it now.

Comment: many good answers. thanks. had to choose one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `var x = x;` doesn't see the variable `x` from the outer scope. The variable `x` inside the scope already exists before the assignment, and shadows the variable from the outer scope.

All variables in the scope are created before the code in the scope executes (hoisted), so it's the same as if you had:

```
(function(){
  var x;
  x = 23;
  return function(){
    var x;
    x = x;
    return x;
  }
}())();
```

---

It actually doesn't matter where in the scope you declare the variables. You can declare them last in the code (although that would be a bit confusing), and the code still works the same:

```
(function(){
  x = 23;
  return function(){
    x = x;
    return x;
    var x;
  }
  var x;
}())();
```

Comment: Thanks that explains it. I don't see how this behavior makes sense though.

Comment: @user3280015: If it was otherwise you would get into several inconsistencies. For example in a loop, a variable could mean one thing the first iteration and another thing the next.

Comment: @user3280015: It might work in some languages (there are a lot of them), but most commonly used languages has some kind of scope for the variables which means that the assignment doesn't see the variable from the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the var x = x; part be sufficiently unambiguous because the right hand side implicitly refers to the x in the outer scope?

No. All the scope of variables is determined before any assignments are performed.

Comment: The language specification does not explain why it was designed that way. (OTOH, I fail to understand why it would be a good idea to allow two different variables to have the same name at different times within a single scope).

Comment: Quentin, it would be two different variables with the same name in two different scopes. And I can imagine several use cases for that.

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept called variable hoisting.. i.e in short, just before executing the function, all variables that are declared inside function will be marked undefined. so it returns undefined.. Because of variable hoisting, you can define variable later but can use it before.. eg. `function(){alert(x);var x;}` will alert undefined but where as `function(){alert(x);}` throws error..

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
(function(){
  var x = 23;
  return function(){
    var x = x;
    return x;
  }
}())();
```

The inner function only sees the inner *x*.

When entering an execution context, all declared variables are initialised, given the value *undefined* and placed on a kind of variable object before any code is executed (such as assignments). All outer variables are placed on a scope chain.

When resolving identifiers, the variable object is checked first, and only if not found there is the scope chain checked.