# cannot read a variable from the global context

Tags: javascript

**JS:**

```
var a = 10;

function test() {
    alert(a);
    var a = 20;
    alert(a);
}

test();
```

The above code was discussed earlier with an interviewer yesterday, i said first time browser would alert 10 and for the next time it would alert 20, but i was wrong. It alerted undefined for the first time and 20 for the second time. I am confused and can anybody theoretically as well as practically explain what's going behind this..?

Relevant link would be very helpful.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Gs54T/)

Comment: Parser found your `var` keyword, so it created local scope var `a` before assignments inside function are really executed. This is called "hoisting", I believe you can find many good articles by this keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243365/why-doesnt-the-outer-scope-variable-get-properly-bound-to-the-inner-variable/24243591

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a function, every `var` is treated as if it appeared at the very top of the function. Thus your code is interpreted as if it were written:

```
function test() {
  var a;
  alert(a);
  a = 20;
  alert(a);
}
```

It's called *hoisting*. Note that it's the **declaration** that's hoisted, not the initialization assignment.

The effect here is that everywhere inside that function, `a` refers to the local variable, which hides the relatively global `a` from view.

[Here is the relevant section of the ES5 spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) It's somewhat opaque.

Comment: Really helpful... And if you were in my place yesterday, you could have cracked the interview easily.. but i was struggled a bit.. :) :) Accept this soon..

Answer (score 1):

When your variable is found in the local scope of the function then it doesnt refer to the global variable. The scope of the global variable is hidden inside the function and hence you are getting the undefined value for the first time.

This concept is called **Hoisting** ie, In JavaScript, a variable can be declared after it has been used. In other words; a variable can be used before it has been declared.